# image management code?

Tags: asp.net

two days back i ask a question for image management, i get some reference that is 4guys
the code is working fine i want to store that manged image in a folder but i not understand how can i save, can u help me. this is my code.....

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public bool ThumbnailCallback()
    {
        return false;
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort dummyCallBack = default(System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort);
        dummyCallBack = new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);

        System.Drawing.Image fullSizeImg = default(System.Drawing.Image);
        fullSizeImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\05.jpg");

        System.Drawing.Image thumbNailImg = default(System.Drawing.Image);
        thumbNailImg = fullSizeImg.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, dummyCallBack, IntPtr.Zero);


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you know that you can assign a variable as it is declared?

Comment: this  is the code i get from 4guys where it is reducing the image size

Comment: You need to learn C# and ASP.Net.  You cannot write a complete program by copying code from websites and asking questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: when i write like this thumbNailImg.Save("~/Image"); i get the error 
A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Comment: Mr.Slaks i learn C# and asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To  save an image to a folder on the server, call [`image.Save(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx).

**EDIT**: You can send a smaller version of an image to the browser like this:

```
using(Image originalImage = something)
using(Bitmap smallImage = new Bitmap(originalImage, width, height)) {
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();    
    smallImage.Save(stream);
    Response.OutputStream.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.Length);
}
```

Comment: sorry i did some mistake i just now edited my question check out actually it is like this only

Comment: how can i display the image, when it is resized

Comment: this is the reference where i get the code
http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012203-1.aspx